# How to re-install dvd-driver in ubuntu

Tags: drivers

I have removed the dvd-rom drive from my laptop(not the disk). When I install the drive again. The device didn't displayed in /dev/cdrom or /dev/dvd

Is there a command that can make ubuntu scan for new hardware and install the driver?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu automatically scans for new hardware. Check if you have connect the driver properly. Check if it is visible in the BIOS. If not then probably it is damaged.

Comment: This dvd drive works. I can boot my laptop with ubuntu installation disk.

Comment: Normally the dvd disk will be mount to /media/dvd
But now nothing happens when I install the dvd drive or insert a disk.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command in Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and observe what happens next:

```
sudo udevadm monitor
```

It could help you to troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Install [cdde [image: Install cdde]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cdde) from Ubuntu Software Centre.. It works with mine.