# Is there a program that I can use to find my drivers?

Tags: drivers

Ubuntu doesn't recognize or cannot find my built in cd/dvd driver nor my bluetooth device. I would really like to enjoy burning my works on cd and dvd.

Comment: show the results from `lsusb` and `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` and if there are any results from `hciconfig --all` please include in an edit to your question using the <$> to insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Noclip726 
Go to **Search your computer and online sources** and type **Software Updater** Click on that and it will directly install any available updates.
OR
You can open Terminal by Typing "Ctrl+Alt+T" and Run `sudo apt-get update`
Hope you will be able to install all softwares.

Comment: OR Read the answers http://askubuntu.com/questions/51809/how-to-re-install-dvd-driver-in-ubuntu